# Distorted UV unwrap

Tags: uv

So I know this is a common issue but i'm hoping someone can shed some light on it for me...

[image]

[image]

[image]

What approach do i need to take in order to unwrap the main body of the cylinder so that is not slanted. I know I can individually align each UV edge to the Y & X axis but im curious to know if there's a more time saving way of doing this?

Comment: What does Follow Active Quads or Cylinder Projection give?

Comment: Hi Moonboots. Thanks for the reply. Cylinder project is what I have had to go with for now (this option gives me straight UV's) but this option doesn't take into account the edge seems for the extruded in section, so this part of the texture is now distorted. Follow active quads gives me a different but equally distorted unwrap. For all intents and purposes for this project the Cylinder Projection works as i only need the unwrap to add some text to cylinder body. I figure I can cylinder project the main body and unwrap the extruded section separately and combine

Comment: Mmmh... Follow Active Quads sould not be distorted, and yes, do the extrusion apart

Comment: I guess I can't upload the image here but the results are straight but still sloped if that makes sense. Anyway.. your suggestion for the cylinder projection solved this issue so thank you.

Comment: There was a scripted called Quad Unwrap that I used to use back in 2.79 that could give a more grid like UV unwrap for cylindrical objects all though I'm not sure how it will handle your cut out in your object, If you have 2.79 still maybe you can unwrap part of it there then just re-import into 2.8.      Here's a youtube video demoing the script,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcFEdK5TQv0&t=6s